# SPD error "Controls in this category require a Microsoft Sharepoint Publishing Page Layout" in toolbox Page Fields & Content Fields

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout

I'm trying to create a page layout on SharePoint 2010, based on a new Page Layout Content Type subclassed from the Publishing Content Type "Page". I got the new content type created ok, with existing site columns added fine using SharePoint Designer, and some new ones added with the web interface. When I try to create the page layout with SPD, I get a bizarre blank alert popup asking me to "OK". I "OK"ed I notice the page layout has been created.

Then I follow instructions in [1] to open the toolbox "Page Fields" & "Content Fields" but I see this error in SPD under each of "Page Fields" & "Content Fields":

> ERROR:"Controls in this category require a Microsoft SharePoint
>   Publishing Page Layout" in the Toolbox pane.

The publishing site collection feature is activated in "/support", as is the publishing site feature in the site I want the page layout: "/support/learning".

Thanks!

**REFERENCES**
[1] Book: Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010 Unleashed (2011) Kathy Hughes (SAMS), chapter 15

**Update**
I repeated these steps on our pre-production farm and did NOT get the error. I still have it on production...

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread, but this is the only thread I could find on the internet that mention this error. I'm currently getting the same error in SPD on a Sharepoint 2013 site. It worked as expected before, and I suddenly noticed it had appeared. The error is the same as described in the original post, "Controls in this category require a Microsoft SharePoint Publishing Page Layout". If I create a new page layout from Design Manager with default Master Page and inheriting Welcome page it produces the same error. It's also present on all site collections, even those I have just created a

Answer (score 1):

I got this multiple time when I tried to create page layout from SPD, seems that custom page layout was not associated with publishing on creation time. I would ensure this by re-creating the layout with web interface from Master Pages gallery; you can use "New Document" button on the ribbon and choose Page Layout here. You can modify it then with SPD. That way it always worked for me.